# Saving a photo taking a very long time

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-camera, react-native-fs

I want users to be able to take photos from within my app and have the photos save to their gallery (so that I can later view them in a photo-picker).

I have the following code from react-native-camera, it's basically the bare-bones demo code.

```
takePicture() {
    const options = { quality: 0.5, fixOrientation: false, width: 1920 };
    if (this.camera) {
      this.camera
        .takePictureAsync(options)
        .then(data => {
             this.saveImage(data.uri);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.error("capture picture error", err);
        });
    } else {
      console.error("No camera found!");
    }
  }
}
```

To move the attachment, I am using react-native-fs, as follows (more basic demo-y code):

```
const dirHome = Platform.select({
  ios: `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/Pictures`,
  android: `${RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath}/Pictures`
});

const dirPictures = `${dirHome}/MyAppName`;

saveImage = async filePath => {
    try {
      // set new image name and filepath
      const newImageName = `${moment().format("DDMMYY_HHmmSSS")}.jpg`;
      const newFilepath = `${dirPictures}/${newImageName}`;
      // move and save image to new filepath
      const imageMoved = await this.moveAttachment(filePath, newFilepath);
      console.log("image moved: ", imageMoved);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  moveAttachment = async (filePath, newFilepath) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      RNFS.mkdir(dirPictures)
        .then(() => {
          RNFS.moveFile(filePath, newFilepath)
            .then(() => {
              console.log("FILE MOVED", filePath, newFilepath);
              resolve(true);
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log("moveFile error", error);
              reject(error);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("mkdir error", err);
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  };
```

When taking a photo, this code executes and prints that the image has been moved within a couple of seconds. But, when I look into the built in Gallery App on the device, it often takes *several minutes* for the image to finally load. I've tried this across many different devices, both emulated and physical... am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `Saving a photo taking a very long time` Clearly a wrong subject. Saving does not take long you confirmed. Appearing in Galley takes long. Quite diffrent.

Comment: `To move the attachment,` Which attachment? Is there an attachment? What has it to do with the picture taken? And why would you move it?

Comment: Further: The MediaStore needs time to discover new files. Now and the it does a rescan on its own. You wait for that. But you can also invoke the media scanner to index your file right away.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by Android's Media Scanner not immediately realizing new files existed.

From this Git issue and the subsequent PR: https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs/issues/79

I modified my code as follows:

```
  saveImage = async filePath => {
    try {
      // set new image name and filepath
      const newImageName = `${moment().format("DDMMYY_HHmmSSS")}.jpg`;
      const newFilepath = `${dirPicutures}/${newImageName}`;
      // move and save image to new filepath
      const imageMoved = await this.moveAttachment(filePath, newFilepath).then(
        imageMoved => {
          if (imageMoved) {
            return RNFS.scanFile(newFilepath);
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      );
      console.log("image moved", imageMoved);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

using RNFS's scanFile method to force the Media Scanner to realize the file exists. This is rough code I'll need to clean up, but it gets the job done.